# Looking for a GUI calculator which has support for two zeroes and history

Tags: linux, debian, gui, calculator

Most of the calculators, for e.g. mate-calc and galculator are good enough for simple needs. There are two functions which I need and want to use in the calculator -

1. It should have support for two zeroes in addition to single zero.
2. It should have support for history so if I have multiple additions going on, I could trace back (like history) to see if the numbers I entered were correct or not, and if not be able to correct it.
3. This would be a wishlist - if the calculator were to have history of its own of previous calculations done so much the better.

While 1. and 2. is available in casio calculators for 20-30 or more odd years now, why don't we have it. If there is, apologies and share the same.

The third should also be possible, just like we have 'history' we should have the same functionality into this calculator as well. FWIW I did try all the other modes in mate-calc as well as other calculators but did not find the above functionality.

[image: mate-calc]

[image: casio business calculator from amazon]

Comment: Have a look at speedcrunch. At least it has a history, and many settings are possible. Please check if it fits your other needs.

Comment: I ain't never seen no analog calculator. What's it use, pneumatics?

Comment: gnome-calculator in a current version should do that (don't know what "two zeroes" means, but history function does work. @Gypsy: Analog calculators were used in ancient times (60's and 70's) e.g. for the integration of differential equations, when digital calculators were not fast enough.

Comment: @ridgy The only analog calculator I can imagine is a slide rule. Which I no longer recall how to use. AFAIRC even the mechanical calculators were digital.

Comment: @Gypsy Off topic now, but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer

Comment: I actually meant casio calculators, so probably 'digital computers with very limited memory' perhaps might have been more appropriate. Have corrected that part.

Comment: @ridgy by two zeroes, I mean to denote hundred multiples, so if I want to write 100, I just press the 00 digit once and 100 comes so for higher figures, don't have to press 0 at all but can use the '00' ones and do my work.

Comment: @shirish I'm glad you specified what two zeros means to you. I had thought it was referring to systems of equations with two zeros, as in solving quadratic systems by subtraction, etc. IIRC the manual calculators, both hand-held and desktop, that had the double-zero button were primarily target at financial workers. That key made entering full dollar amounts, i.e. no cents, easier since it was one button press rather than two. About half the time those same calculators also assumed that there was _always_ two decimal places, sometimes they didn't have the decimal key.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver fwiw I also shared a picture of the kind of the calculator I meant as well as filed a wishlist bug/ticket at https://bitbucket.org/heldercorreia/speedcrunch/issues/704/have-two-zeroes-along-with-one-zero-in

Comment: as well as https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=778893 Let's see if either of the above work out.